# How do I delete documents created after a certain date in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am in the Atlas application and I have added on Sunday November 22 a series of documents that I want to delete.

How can I delete documents created after a certain date in MongoDB?

I searched the Internet, but mainly found how to delete before, and nothing about how to do it from the MongoDB application.

I mainly use the python in a different way when I want to manipulate the client side

Here is an example of an early document:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5fab2fb0132a637dbb7ad882"},"img":"//img.xssdcdn.com/perfume/216962.jpg","id":"216962","enname":"Atelier Cologne Cedre Atlas, 2015","cnname":"欧珑 雪松之恋","调香师":"JeromeEpinette标签","brand":"欧珑","fragrance":"木质调","top":"香柠檬柠檬黑加仑","middle":"雪松茉莉杏","base":"琥珀纸莎草香根草","attribut":"中性香","isscore":"8.3 ","istotal":"673 人评分","stars":{"5星":"28%","4星":"31%","3星":"26%","2星":"10%","1星":"5%"},"intro":"\nCedre Atlas是Atelier Cologne Collection Azur系列 的一员。这个系列还包括冰冻橘子Mandarine，炙热无花果Figuier Ardent，南方玉兰Sud Magnolia。\n...展开\n","short_comments":[{"name":"\nSheyla\r\n　","comment":"闻了一堆欧珑，可以确认这个品牌不适合我"}],"likebys_id":["947895","350870","251428","705357","255114"]}
```

Comment: Can you please post example JSON of the documents that you are trying to delete?

Comment: @TheDoctor Sure, just did, removed part of it as the editor detects Chinese characters as spam

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't introduce any `_id` manually then documents can be removed based on `_id`.

- Older documents have larger values.

I tested with this document set:

```
> db.TEST.insert([{_id:ObjectId("ffbba8cb165f77b0ec90921c") }, {_id:ObjectId("3fbba8cb165f77b0ec90921c") }, {_id:ObjectId("ffbba8cb165f77b0ec909215") }, {_id:ObjectId("5fbba8cb165f77b0ec90921c") } ])
```

```
 db.TEST.deleteMany({$expr:{$gte:["$_id",ObjectId("5fbba8cb165f77b0ec90921c")]}})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 3 }

db.TEST.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3fbba8cb165f77b0ec90921c") }
```

1. Find the `_id` of element inserted in your reference date
2. The remove any element with id larger than that.

```
 db.TEST.deleteMany({$expr:{$gte:["$_id",ObjectId("referenceID")]}})
```

---

To find your reference ID do this:

```
db.TEST.findOne({_id:ObjectId(IDtestForDate)})._id.getTimestamp()
```